# How to run a batch file at a specific time and kill it once it runs for a number of hours

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a bat file which I run with an externally given parameter. It should run for about 6 hours and if the task is still not finished, the process should get killed. I can start the task using Task Scheduler but I'm not sure how to kill it once it reaches the set number of hours. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: So start time plus 7 hours.

Comment: Your question includes no failing code, and does indicate the reference material you've found, what you've tried, or what happened when you did, which did not meet with your expectations. Those things are required for a properly posed question on this site. We are not here to do your research for you, so that you don't have to, tutor you step by step, or to write code for you to your specifications. Please use the search facility at the top of the page, and take time to go through each of the linked topics within the [ask] pages; thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Task Scheduler use "Create Task" (not "Create Basic Task").

On the Settings screen there is the option labelled "Stop the task if it runs longer than:".

You can override the length of time.